# Problems while using Update manager

Tags: update-manager, updates

I am getting the following messages while using Update Manger ...how to resolve this ??

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libcaribou0: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but 2.13-20ubuntu5 is installed
             Depends: libgee2 (>= 0.5.0) but 0.6.2.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
             Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.27.5) but 2.31.0-0ubuntu1~oneiric1 is installed
             Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0) but 3.2.1-0ubuntu1~11.10~ricotz0 is installed
             Depends: libxklavier16 (>= 5.1) but 5.1-1ubuntu1 is installed
             Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.7.4) but 2.7.8.dfsg-4 is installed
             Depends: libcaribou-common (= 0.4.1-0ubuntu1~11.10~ricotz0) but it is not installed
```

Comment: Did you try and enable the on screen keyboard and receive an error? 

The package `libcaribou-common` needs to be installed according to your log, it also forms part of the Gnome Shell dependencies according to [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/367071).  It would help if you explained what you have done to get to this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 1):

A bug report was filed for this [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/caribou/+question/176122). If you follow the comments, hopefully your problem should be fixed. If not, it may be worth trying to post your problems you encountered there and trying to get it fixed, as it is the Ubuntu bug report tracker.